# "Unexpected. Please try again." error when performing simple query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-bigquery

I keep receiving a status 500 error: "Unexpected. Please try again" message when I perform a query using the Ruby client. This query works when I input this into the API explorer on the google site.

Here is the code:

```
result = client.execute(
  :api_method => bigquery.jobs.query,
  :parameters => {"projectId" => "projectId"},
  :body_object => { "kind" => "bigquery#queryRequest", "query" => "SELECT date FROM
  [google.com:adsense-reports:Reports.DailyAdUnitReport] WHERE date = CURRENT_DATE()"}
  )
```

Is there an error in this syntax?

Answer (score 0):

When you say `{"projectId" => "projectId"}` did you actually have your project-ID in the code and redacted it here or did you pass the string "projectID" there?

If the latter is true, you might want to substitute that to pass your project-id which is a string that can be found in the project console here: https://cloud.google.com/console/project